# How can I disable the free list(Python cache mechanism) in Python? (return the memory to OS)

Tags: python

Python has free list which can cache the list, dict, set, tuple, float. That means we can not really free the memory and return it back to OS. For example:

```
import gc
a = []
n = 100000
for i in range(n):
    a.append({i: i})
a_addr = id(a)
del a  # the reference count minus one
gc.collect()  # doesn't work, not really free the memory

b = []
m = 100
for i in range(m):
    b.append(i)
print(a_addr == id(b))  # True which means, the list a is cached, a new list b created and use list a address from free list.
```

My question is can I have some ways to disable this mechanism?

Why I want to disable it, because I meet the scenario which need to free the memory.
I use Flask-APSchedular to do a memory-costly task every day. And I used Gunicorn as a server. I just started 4 works, I used Redis lock, avoiding to executing tasks simultaneously in both 4 works. However, after the application running a couple of days, all of 4 works' memory are full, and the task won't be executed anymore. I think the solutions are restarting the Gunicorn workers or collect the garbage after task finished. That's why I need to know how to disable the free list in python and really free the memory.

Comment: That's not actually how Python's allocation system works. There's no such unbounded free list. Most types don't have a free list in their allocator at all.

Comment: There used to be an unbounded free list for ints, but it went away when the old fixed-size int type went away.

Comment: Your `print(id(a) == id(b))` doesn't actually print True. It throws a NameError, because the `a` variable is no longer bound. This is independent of memory allocation details.

Comment: I believe the usual solution for this kind of memory concern is to restart workers instead of letting them run indefinitely.

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault, I fix the code, save the id(a) before del and then compare it to id(b).

Comment: That just means `b` happened to be allocated in the same virtual memory address as `a`. Heck, it's not even the data portion of `b` - you're looking at the address of a tiny bit of metadata, separate from the list's buffer. (As it happens, there *is* a [free list](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.5/Objects/listobject.c#L120) for these tiny metadata headers, but it never grows past 80 elements.)

Answer (score 1):

`gc.collect()` already releases the freelists (those which are most relevant anyway e.g. it's possible that the int and float freelists don't do that).

However that just deallocates objects at the Python level, it doesn't mean the *underlying allocator* releases the memory to the OS (or even that it can). Without bypassing the allocator (and mmap-ing memory directly), there is no *generic* way to tell the low-level allocator to release its memory to the OS.

> And I used Gunicorn as a server. I just started 4 works, I used Redis lock, avoiding to executing tasks simultaneously in both 4 works. However, after the application running a couple of days, all of 4 works' memory are full, and the task won't be executed anymore.

It kinda sounds like you have a memory leak though, you probably want to investigate that: normally Python should reach an HWM due to the high-memory task, then stay within those bounds afterwards, so either the task should never succeed or it should always succeed.

But I'd recommend moving the memory-expensive tasks out of the workers regardless (using the process-based executor of APScheduler). You may also want to configure gunicorn to semi-regularly *expire* the workers, it's rarely a bad idea.

Comment: Does `gc.collect()` actually release any freelists? I think it just cleans up circular references.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your recommendation. But does gc.collect() really release any freelists? 
And, as you said, 
normally Python should reach an HWM due to the high-memory task, then stay within those bounds afterwards, so either the task should never succeed or it should always succeed.
My task succeed on first day and second day, but failed on the third day because of memory leak, and that worker which deal with my task are stuck.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, I also do not think gc.collect() can release the freelists. @user2357112 supports Monica

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica yes gc.collect releases freelists when doing a full collection (which is the default), [it's even documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html?highlight=gc%20collect#gc.collect) "The free lists maintained for a number of built-in types are cleared whenever a full collection or collection of the highest generation (2) is run.", and [you can find old issues about hooking up freelists into gc.collect](https://bugs.python.org/issue2862).

Comment: In fact [one of the Python 3.9 changes](https://bugs.python.org/issue40428) is to remove the various `*_ClearFreeList` calls from the official / external C API in favor of people calling `PyGC_Collect` as it calls all of them, and is thus preferrable (shorter, cleaner, and more future-proof).